# Check if any number in array is bigger than given number Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this function which finds the avarage in the array :

```
const findAvarage = (a,b,c,d) =>{
  let total = 0;
  let numbers = [a,b,c,d];

for(let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    total += numbers[i];
}
let avg = total / numbers.length;

console.log("avg",avg)
}

findAvarage(2,2,6,10);
```

Now I need to find out index of number in the array which is bigger than the avarage number,Any suggestions please?

Comment: but in this case there are two numbers bigger than the average, so do you want to get the index of the first occurance, or the biggest one?

Comment: simply `Math.max(a,b,c,d)`

Comment: The first biggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with the `find()` method:

```
const array1 = [2, 2, 6, 10];

const found = array1.find(element => element > findAvarage(2,2,6,10));

console.log(found);
```

If you want to get back the index of the element, use `findIndex()` instead

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: also, findAverage should have the average number as its return value for it to work

Comment: will it find the first biggest number ? I mean if i have like 2 numbers bigger than avg number

Comment: i'll put a runnable for u to see what's returned

Comment: @NikaRoffy `find()` returns the first element that satisfies the condition, or undefined otherwise

Answer (score 1):

```js
const findAvarage = (a,b,c,d) =>{
  let total = 0;
  let numbers = [a,b,c,d];

for(let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    total += numbers[i];
}
let avg = total / numbers.length;

return avg;
}


let arr = [2, 2, 6, 10];

arr=arr.filter(element => element > findAvarage(2,2,6,10));

console.log(arr); //this shows all numbers > average

//now to see the highest number
var yourAnswer = arr.sort()[arr.length-1];
console.log("Your answer is "+yourAnswer);
```

this is just the running version

Answer (score 1):

I saw lot of answers, but none of them has improved the find average function, it is limited to only four digits and it doesn't return the result, and even for finding the biggest number than the average, both should be dynamic

```js
const findAvarage = (...nums) => nums.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / nums.length || 0;

const getBiggestNumberThanTheAverage = (...nums) => {
  let average = findAvarage(...nums);
  return nums.find(num => num > average);
}

console.log(getBiggestNumberThanTheAverage(2, 2, 6, 10));
console.log(getBiggestNumberThanTheAverage(3, 2, 7));
console.log(getBiggestNumberThanTheAverage(7, 5, 9, 10, 18, 8, 1, 6));
```