# Find how many items in array are greater equal or less than given number Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
  let numbers = [2, 2, 6, 10];



const findAvarage = (numbers) => {
  let total = 0;
  let checkIntegers = numbers.every(i => !Number.isInteger(i))

  if (checkIntegers = true) {
    for(let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    total += numbers[i];
  }
  let avg = total / numbers.length;

   return avg
  } else {
    return "Only integers allowed"
  }
 
 const compareNumbers = (numbers) => {
   
 }
```

In this code I calculate the avarage of the given numbers in array and now I want to find how many numbers in array are greater that avarage number with second function

I tried to use find method but it did not work out,any solutions on this please?

Comment: so add an if statement and check and increase a counter

Comment: I shall loop once more in second function other the array and check it one by one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64727348/check-if-any-number-in-array-is-bigger-than-given-number-javascript/64727432#64727432 is an exact replica

Comment: me and a dude solved the question long ago

Comment: as in 15 mins xD

Comment: Ah XD i guess we have the same exam

Comment: but i need to also find numbers less and equal to avarage number

Comment: @anadvali what "exam" is this?

Comment: `greater equal or less`  what does it mean ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` function to filter out the numbers that are larger than average.

```
const avg = findAvarage(numbers)
const count = numbers.filter(number => number > avg).length
```

Comment: yea that was the principle of the last answer, to the same question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64727348/check-if-any-number-in-array-is-bigger-than-given-number-javascript/64727432#64727432

Answer (score 0):

u can use filter or reduce to solve it

```js
let numbers = [2, 2, 6, 10];

function countNumbers(number){
  return numbers.filter(num=> num>=number).length;
}


function countNumbers2(number){
  return numbers.reduce((count,item)=>count+(item>=number),0)
}


console.log(countNumbers(7));
console.log(countNumbers2(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const compareNumbers = (numbers) => {
   const avg = findAvarage(numbers);
   let greater = 0;
   
   numbers.forEach((num) => { if (num > avg) greater++; });

   return greater;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not provide many extension methods that can be used for arrays, you have just some basics operations.
Your code can be more cleaner if you turn this need into extensions for arrays that you can them every where without calling functions, you can do as follow:

```js
Object.defineProperties(Array.prototype, {
    count: {
        value: function(value) {
            if(isNan(value)) return NaN;
            return this.filter(x => x>=value).length;
        }
    },
    average:{
        value:function(){
            let total = 0;
            if(!this.every(i => Number.isInteger(i))) 
               return NaN;
            for(let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
               total += numbers[i];
            }
            return total/this.length;
        }
    }
});
```

and you can use it like this for you example

```js
var result = numbers.count(numbers.average())
```

Answer (score 0):

this way ?

```js
const findAvarage=(a,b,c,d) => [a,b,c,d].reduceRight((t,n,i,a)=>
        {
        t += n
        if (!i) t /= a.length
        return t
        },0)
  ,   greaterOrEqualCount = (a,b,c,d) => 
        {
        let avg = findAvarage(a,b,c,d)
        return [a,b,c,d].reduce((r,n)=>r+(n<avg?0:1),0) 
        } 
    

console.log("count ",greaterOrEqualCount(2,2,6,10))
```